# Detect which button was clicked in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this dropdown menu and I want to know which button is clicked:

```
btnMenu = Menubutton(f4, text='Select your iPhone:')
contentMenu = Menu(btnMenu)
btnMenu.config(menu=contentMenu)
btnMenu.pack()

btnList = ["iPhone 6", "iPhone 6 Plus","iPhone 6S","iPhone 6S Plus", "iPhone 7", "iPhone 7 Plus","iPhone 8","iPhone 8 Plus","iPhone X"]
```

For example:

```
if "iPhone 6" was clicked:
   Do something
if "iPhone 7" was clicked:
   Do something
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: you have to add commands to the menu

Comment: How? Can you write the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use the `if...else` in the `print_` function

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
 
menubutton = Menubutton(root, text = "Menu")   
    
menu = Menu(menubutton)  
menubutton["menu"]=menu  
def print_(number):
    print(f"Hey! {number} was clicked!")
btnList = ["iPhone 6", "iPhone 6 Plus","iPhone 6S","iPhone 6S Plus", "iPhone 7", "iPhone 7 Plus","iPhone 8","iPhone 8 Plus","iPhone X"]
for i in btnList:
    menu.add_command(label=i,command=lambda i=i: print_(i))
menubutton.pack()  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No. I mean if a button was clicked, do something. Your code only detects which button was clicked and print it on the screen

Comment: I want to know exactly which button was clicked and create a condition for it.

Comment: @HuyVuQuang I am saying that ```number``` parameter contains the text of the button which was clicked. You can add an ```if``` statement like ```if number=='Iphone 6'``` or ```if number=='Iphone X'```

Comment: @HuyVuQuang you don't need to know which button was clicked (if you actually do then explain because I can't imagine a single use case), you need to add a command that is called when button is clicked